# Snakemake: specify cluster per rule

Tags: python, snakemake

I am running a large workflow in snakemake, that employs cluster execution (--cluster qsub) and a custom profile (--profile custom) for execution in a user-specific computing environment. How can I specify which computing environment (cluster, profile or local) to use for every rule?

Otherwise, would it be possible to chain multiple sub-workflows with different execution options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying rules for local execution can be done via `localrules`:

> The keyword localrules allows to mark a rule as local, so that it is not submitted to the cluster and instead executed on the host node

See [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html).

```py
localrules: all, foo

rule all:
    input: ...

rule foo:
    ...

rule bar:
    ...
```

AFAIK it's not possible to specify a custom profile per individual rule.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I realized that I can implement the submission on the user-specific computing environment in a snakemake wrapper, instead of in a profile. Then I can reference the wrapper per rule.